# is there a problem if i call starmap twice or more?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have a problem with using multiprocessing in python3.

When using starmap, I have different length of the argument list such as event_list(length: 8), confs(length:2), overwrite(length:1).

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool
from iteltools import repeat
p = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=3)
for conf in confs:
  p.starmap( some_func, zip(event_list, repeat(conf), repeat(overwrite))
```

The code above works well, but calling starmap twice or more makes me uncomfortable.

Please tell me other better ways to refactor the code.

Comment: why does it make you uncomfortable?

Comment: The code works well, but I barely saw the code calling map or starmap twice or more.
And I look for the simple and clean code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create one generator of values and process it with one starmap expression as follows.  This would be simpler for readers familiar with Python standard library.

```
import multiprocessing
import itertools
p = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=3)
p.starmap(some_func, itertools.product(event_list, confs, overwrite))
```

Comment: Thank you. The code works well and seems to be simple and clean.